# foreman can't find java

Tags: java, windows-7, environment-variables, mingw32, foreman

I'm trying to use foreman to run a java app locally which deploys fine to heroku.

My Procfile looks like this

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes;target/dependency/* Start
```

but when i do `formeman start` i get

```
15:51:21 web.1  | unknown command: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes;target/dependency/* Start
```

If I just enter `java` at the prompt i get java's help text back so its on my path.  If I use the full path to the java executable in the Procfile it works, but it'd be cleaner if I didn't need two versions of the Procfile

Is there somethinf funky going on with my path or is foreman not getting the path from my environment?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the environment variable is the problem?

Windows:

```
    java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp target/classes;target/dependency/* Start
```

Linux:

```
    java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Start
```

Looks like the example is a mix of both :-)

[Environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)

Comment: I too am facing the issue describe in the Q and although this didn't help resolve the original problem (ended up using `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java%`) ... it did help me fix all the others :)

Comment: Glad to hear it :-) `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java%` looks strange - why don't you leave the trailing sign? (`%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java`)