# Foreman cannot find $JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java, heroku, windows-7-x64, foreman

I have an error following the next tutorial from Heroku specifically on this part

[https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#run-the-app-locally][1]

If I execute that instruction foreman throws the following error:

**Error: cannot find java class $JAVA_OPTS**

I have already declared a env variable like this:

```
Name variable : JAVA_OPTS

Variable value: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

The Proc file that foreman is trying to execute has the following:

```
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main
```

Im clueless about what is happening.

Note: I already checked some other questions

[Running java with JAVA_OPTS env variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011311/running-java-with-java-opts-env-variable)

[Foreman terminates immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177496/foreman-terminates-immediately)

[foreman can't find java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390632/foreman-cant-find-java)

Hope someone knwos what is happening.

**EDIT : I answered my own question below**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are running on Windows. If so, then you'll have to reference the JAVA_OPTS var like `%JAVA_OPTS%`. But Heroku will still need the *nix style (`$JAVA_OPTS`), so I recommend creating a `Procfile.win` next to your `Procfile` with the following contents:

```
web: java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main
```

Then run this to start your app locally:

```
$ foreman start --procfile=Procfile.win
```

Comment: This helped me a lot to find the right solution, for the record Im gonna add a new answer but I will mark it as the valid.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did in order to solve the issue:

Seems that the documentation at heroku site is not clear about what operating system are you using. But then I found the answer in the link below:

[Heroku Deploy your Java app locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java-o#build-and-run-your-app-locally)

The original Proc file script whas like this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main
```

and I modified it as you can see below:

```
web: java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp target\classes;"target\dependency\*"  Main
```

Just as Heroku documentation states.

This solved the problem and I was able to run my app locally

Comment: That semicolon is critical in Windows! This deserves being the right answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 'nix,

`export JAVA_OPTS`

before running the script that expects it.

Comment: Excuse me, do you have a link or reference of how to do that? Btw I am using windows 7.